# jquery each('.someclass') visible count

Tags: jquery, count, each, visible

Being new to jQuery I have this simple question:

Given a set of thumbnail images, sharing the same class, some are visible, some are not.

What is the best way to count the number of elements sharing the same class and is(':visible')?

Answer (score 3):

No need for a loop, you can just do:

```
var visible_images = $('.myClass:visible').length;
```

or

```
var visible_images = $('.myClass').filter(':visible').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myclass:visible').length
```

The pseudo-class selectors can be used as part of the element/class/id selector string